# How to Check if a Scanner Was Closed

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with two methods I have been trying to write. Both involve using a Scanner to read in a file, where each line is comma delimited. The methods are a part of my FileIO class. In addition to that class, I also have two other classes, Food and FoodArrayList. Food objects contain several pieces of information from food donations (who donated the items, the reason for the donation, etc.). The FoodArrayList class pretty much has the same functionality as an ArrayList, except that I've created it solely for the purpose to store Food objects.

The two methods I am struggling with are as follows:

1. Reads in the file and simply counts the number of lines in the file. It returns the number of lines. This method is used to determine the size of a FoodArrayList. This is because each line of the file describes a Food object.
2. Reads in the file and stores the information into a FoodArrayList object. Remember that each comma-delimited line describes a Food object. Hence, this method goes through the file, creates Food objects, and inserts them into a FoodArrayList until it reaches the end of the file.

What I am struggling with is that I close my Scanner in both of the methods. And I've been struggling with how to write an `if` statement to detect if a Scanner was closed. In both of the methods, I have the following at the very beginning of the method:

```
    try{
        if(scan.hasNext() == false || scan == null)
            scan = new Scanner(new File(this.getFileName()));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.err.println("The " + fileName + " could not be found.");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work though. If I use method #1 first and then later on try to use method #2 (remember that I close the Scanner at the end of each method), the `if` statement is skipped and `scan` is never reinstantiated and I am thrown an `IllegalStateException`.

**A very big point that I should have mentioned earlier is this:** I want both methods to be reusable. If method #1 goes on until the end of file and I later on use method #2, I would want the Scanner object to be reading from the beginning of the file again. And it seems that the only way to do this is to reinstantiate the Scanner object.

When I first learned about I/O in Java, I remember being told to *always* make sure to close Scanner objects when you're done using them. That's something that has been ingrained into my brain almost. Regardless, how do I get around this? One thought I had was to set `scan` to null at the end of both of my methods. Is that even necessary? I've read on other posts in StackOverflow that would lead me to not even closing my Scanner object and just let the garbage collector take care of it.

In addition to all of this, I was also wondering what exactly happens to a Scanner once it is closed and why it can't be reopened. I understand that it has something to do with Streams, but I don't exactly know what those are in the context of Java. I tried looking up the [Stream class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), but was not able to obtain much of an understanding from it.

Here is the code from both of my methods:

**Method #1**

```
public int numberOfLines(){
    try{
        if(scan.hasNext() == false || scan == null)
            scan = new Scanner(new File(this.getFileName()));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.err.println("The " + fileName + " could not be found.");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    int lineCount = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        scan.nextLine();
        lineCount++;
    }
    scan.close();
    return lineCount;
}
```

**Method #2**

```
public void readFile(FoodArrayList fal){
    try{
        if(scan.hasNext() == false || scan == null)
            scan = new Scanner(new File(this.getFileName()));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.err.println("The " + fileName + " could not be found.");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String stringRead = scan.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(stringRead,",");
        Food temp = new Food();
        temp.setCorpName(tokens.nextToken());
        temp.getContact().setLast(tokens.nextToken());
        temp.getContact().setFirst(tokens.nextToken());
        temp.setDate(tokens.nextToken());
        temp.setProductCode(tokens.nextToken());
        temp.setDescription(tokens.nextToken());
        temp.setReason(tokens.nextToken());
        String numberString = tokens.nextToken();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        temp.setNumber(number);
        temp.setCoP(tokens.nextToken());
        fal.insert((Food)temp);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

I'd like to keep these two methods separate. This is because in my client class, I am performing the following:

```
    FoodArrayList list;
    FileIO fio = new FileIO();
    int listSize = fio.numberOfLines();     
    list = new FoodArrayList(listSize);     
    fio.readFile(list);
```

The default constructor of my FileIO class already considers the particular file I am attempting to read. Of course, the overloaded constructor allows one to use a different filename as an input. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `if(scan.hasNext() == false || scan == null)` you should swap the conditions, because if there is possibility of `scan` object being `null` then you should check it first. Also you need the first method only if you are storing the `Food` objects in a array. But I am guessing you are already using some collection, not required line count.

Comment: what is FoodArrayList list? what exactly do you want to do when you call its constructor and pass listsize  as an argument?

Comment: FoodArrayList is a class that operates the same as an ArrayList object, except that it is designed to only store Food objects. I know I could have just used an instance of ArrayList, but I have my reasons for creating this particular class. When I pass listSize as an argument, I am basically creating an array of Food objects with the size of listSize.

Comment: I could have just manually counted the number of lines in the file and in my code put in `list = new FoodArrayList(24)`. However, from what I understand of the coding profession, we typically want to avoid hard-coding things and make our code flexible. This is why I created the `numberOfLines()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want both methods to be reusable. If method #1 goes on until the end of file and I later on use method #2, I would want the Scanner object to be reading from the beginning of the file again. And it seems that the only way to do this is to reinstantiate the Scanner object.

It seems like you have your answer here.  You want to reinstantiate the `Scanner` object irrespective of what state one of them may have been in, so just...do that.

At the beginning of your methods, declare and instantiate your `Scanner` reference.  You could also use `try-with-resources` so that your `Scanner` is always closed at the end of its run.

```
public void countLines() {
    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"))) {
        // code
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Even though in reality the work you're doing could be accomplished in the same method, if you insist on performing these operations separately, then initializing two different `Scanner`s is your best option.

Comment: I follow what you're saying. However, these two methods are a part of the FileIO class. In my constructors, I already instantiate my Scanner object.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your point though. . . Are you saying to not to even use the `if` statement and reinstantiate the Scanner regardless? That way, it wouldn't matter how I defined my constructors for the FileIO class because I'd want these methods to start from the beginning of the file each time they're used. And reinstantiating Scanner objects is the only way to start from the beginning of the file read.

Comment: And I want the work to be done in two separate methods. That's because in my client class, I have the following code:

`FoodArrayList list;`
`FileIO fio = new FileIO();`
`int listSize = fio.numberOfLines();`
`list = new FoodArrayList(listSize);`
`fio.readFile(list);`

Kind of hard to see my point in a comment. I can add this code to the main question if you'd like.

Comment: You won't be able to paste the code in a comment.  Even if you could, it'd look terrible.

Comment: Just added the client code to my question. Hope that clarifies what I'm trying to achieve (and is more readable).